# Is there an hg equivalent to git-info?

Tags: git, mercurial, debian

I have git-info which is part of git-extras. I am actually looking to know the remote repository URL -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~/games/libcpuid] - [10328]
└─[$] git-info

## Remote URLs:

origin  https://github.com/anrieff/libcpuid (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/anrieff/libcpuid (push)

## Remote Branches:

  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master

## Local Branches:

* master

## Most Recent Commit:

commit fa87a5e183a3809ded89ecb3efde4e94837c5736
Author: Veselin Georgiev <anrieff@gmail.com>

    Fixed issue #78: date in changelog is wrong

Type 'git log' for more commits, or 'git show <commit id>' for full commit details.

## Configuration (.git/config):

user.name=Shirish Agarwal
user.email=shirishag75@gmail.com
core.editor=leafpad
core.excludesfiles=/home/shirish/.gitignore
core.gitproxy="ssh" for gitorious.org
merge.tool=meld
push.default=simple
color.ui=true
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/anrieff/libcpuid
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

I tried if there was something from an hg side but came up empty :(

Any ideas anybody how to get remote repo info onto CLI in Hg/mercurial instance ?

I did look at https://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/02/mercurial-vs-git-why-mercurial/ but couldn't find an equivalent command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want are the URLs:

```
$ hg paths
default = https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg
```

See `hg help paths`, `hg help urls`, and `hg help config`.